# Does C++ read binary numbers as two's complement by default?

Tags: c++, binary, type-conversion

I have a piece of code reading two bytes from a hardware's registers:

```
short MPU9250::combineRegisters(unsigned char msb, unsigned char lsb){
        //shift the MSB left by 8 bits and OR with LSB
        return ((short)msb<<8)|(short)lsb;
    }
```

the actual data in the device is in big Endian format, so I read two bytes and combine them to get the real value in two's complement form. However, when I'm outputting the data to the console, like:

```
cout << combineRegisters(registerA, registerB) << endl;
```

C++ automatically gives me integer values with appropriate plus/minus sign. I didn't specify that the binary value I got from the devices is of two's complement form.

How is that? Does that mean C++ reads binary values and assume that they are two's complement format?

Comment: Non prefixed short is often signed.

Comment: Argh, how did you misspell your own username...

Comment: FYI, you seem to misunderstand some terms. *"Endian format"* makes no sense. It could be either big-endian or little-endian and it's (almost) always one of those two.

Comment: @KerrekSB intentionally did that. hah..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thx for pointing that out, yes, that's big endian.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi That's true but say for example if I assigned a binary 11000011 to a short variable, and I didn't specify that's two's complement. How does C++ know that's -61, instead of 195?

Comment: @Nonexistant the upper half is positive, the rest is negative. See Wikipedia article for [signedness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness)

Comment: You've forced the raw bits into the ***signed*** short of the platform you compiled for. If the platform uses two-complement, that's how the raw bytes will be interpreted. If you compile for some platform that uses a different convention, the bits will be interpreted using that convention.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi Thank you! That makes so much sense! Just double checking with you, it means that the value I got from the device is not actually in two's complement. But by assigning that to a short variable, the 0~2^15 part was pushed to the negative side, and 2^15+1~2^16 part was pushed to positive side.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi also from the manufacture data sheet of that device, it didn't say that the reading is in two's complement, so I think it should be regular binary format. and just like you said, it's the signed short-type-conversion does the trick splitting the value into upper-positive and lower-negative parts.

Comment: *"it didn't say that the reading is in two's complement, so I think it should be regular binary format"* There is no 'regular binary format' for signed numbers. A signed integer is (almost always) either two's complement or one's complement.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you! Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

`ostream::operator<<()` detects in compile time types of argument - in your case `short`. It is a type with sign, so you can do 2 things

Cast value returned from function

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned short>(combineRegisters(registerA, registerB)) << endl;
```

or modify function itself

```
unsigned short MPU9250::combineRegisters(unsigned char msb, unsigned char lsb) {
    //shift the MSB left by 8 bits and OR with LSB
    return (static_cast<unsigned short>(msb << 8) | static_cast<unsigned short>(lsb);
}
```

I recomend second variant because you have no intention of returning negative values from `MPU9250::combineRegisters` function.